# How can i get one table id values to another table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a two tables in my database.  One is "blog" second is "comment".

Blog table have this structure 
id, title, text, writer_id, created_at, updated_at
Comment table have this structure 
id, blog_id, text, commenter_id, created_at, updated_at

I want to get id value from blog table as in comment table in the form of blog_id .  How can i get the same value.

Example:

One blog posted. blog table have these values. 
id: 1
title: hi i m blogger
text: how are you
writer_id: 5 (same User id)
created_at:25 feb
updated_at: 25 feb
Blog posted . One commenter comes and comment on this post. Value should be comes as like this in comment table
id=1 
blog_id:1
text: ok i know
created_at:25 feb
updated_at: 25 feb

id of blog table and blog_id of comment table should be same. How can i do this with query or php code?.

Comment: Use Join to get all comment of blog.

Comment: Your question is too broad and general. It wouldbe good if you could show us some code.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Query

```
SELECT b.id, c.`text`,..... FROM blog b
LEFT JOIN comment c
ON b.id = c.blog_id 
ORDER BY commenter_id DESC ;
```

if you want for perticular blog so add **WHERE** CONDITION

```
 SELECT b.id, c.`text`,.... FROM blog b
    LEFT JOIN comment c
    ON b.id = c.blog_id 
    b.id = 'Your ID'
    ORDER BY commenter_id DESC ;
```

Comment: This query use in controller or in mysql.?

Comment: this is use in mysql

Comment: its will give all blog and his comment whether blog have no any comment. so use the LEFT JOIN. if you want only those post which have comment then use the INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all you have to put foreign constraint that the value of column "Blog_Id" in table comment should always be from table "blog"
- `select * from blog bg inner join comment cm on cm.blog_id = blog.id` this is the query for retrieving what you want.